# CakePHP - Pass parameter to controller (NOT url request)

Tags: php, cakephp

There is a function in AppController:

```
function products()  
{  
    $products=$this->Product->find('all',array('order' => array('Product.publish_order  ASC') ,'fields'=>array('id','name','price','publish')));  
    $this->set('products',$products);  
    $counter=$this->Pincode->find('count',array('order' => array('Pincode.product_id DESC '),'conditions' => array('product_id' => $pid,'status'=>0)));  
    $this->set('counter',$counter);  
}
```

In my layout products.ctp I need to set a **$pid** (as you see in appcontroller class method I used this) and pass it through.

Comment: You only have two options: Either as POST via form or as GET via URL passed params or query strings.

Comment: You mean there is no setters?

Comment: @wertvoll the distinction between server-side processing and client-side HTML is clear to you? How should a HTML page displayed in a browser be able to "call a setter" for your server-side code?

Comment: CakePHP layout structure is clear to you? that's written(might) in PHP.

Comment: Use ajax - don't use Session - then you can get your data by $this->request->data['valirable_name']

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the cakephp session

Code to add Value in session :

```
$this->Session->write('Product.id', 25);
```

Code to read Value from session :

```
$pid= $this->Session->read('Product.id');
```

Code to delete Value from session :

```
$this->Session->delete('Product.id');
```

Comment: Session should be avoided as it is highly unstable - especially across multiple tabs the behavior can be quite odd and counter-intuitive.